# Forward-declare typedef struct in c++

Tags: c++, c, struct, typedef, forward-declaration

I am using a legacy lib that defines a struct in Foo.h:

> `typedef struct { int i; int j; } Foo`

However in my C++ program I am trying to write the following in a header file.

```
// forward-declare the struct
struct Foo;

class Bar {
  void myFunction(std::shared_ptr<Foo> foo);
};
```

And in my cpp file:

`#include "Foo.h"`

However this fails with an error:

> typedef redefinition with different types ('struct Foo' vs 'Foo')

What is the correct syntax to do this?

Comment: so, am I assuming correctly the legacy lib is C.

Answer (score 6):

This typedef declaration

```
typedef struct { int i; int j; } Foo;
```

declares the alias Foo for an unnamed structure.

This declaration

```
struct Foo;
```

declares another structure with the name Foo.

These two structures are different. So the name `Foo` is ambiguous.

What you need is just to include the typedef declaration in your own header or to include the header `Foo.h` with the already declared typedef in your own header.

That is neither compilation unit shall contain two typedef declarations of the alias Foo because each unnamed structure introduces a different type though their data member declarations can be the same.